Best word for "[to use as a] crutch"
I am looking for the most natural way to say that something is used as a "crutch", which in English has a very negative connotation.
So far I have found (from EOW):

助け/支え
emotional crutch
情緒的な支え［助け］:
ある種の癖は情緒的な支えとして機能する。
Some mannerisms works as an emotional crutch.
よりどころ
生きてゆくのには心のよりどころが必要だ.
To get by in life you need a source of emotional support.

My problem with these words is that they don't feel outwardly negative as much as "use X as a crutch" in English, as in "I use self-deprecating humor as a crutch to hide my insecurities". It feels off to me to use something like 支え there, but I could be wrong.
I assume to make a sentence like that you would use the XをYにする pattern, but I struggle to find the right noun for it.

I would say 心のよりどころ (心の拠り所 in kanji) is actually a good candidate because it's typically (though not always) used in sarcastic or pitiful contexts like these:

10年前に1回だけヒットしたことを心のよりどころにして今も漫画家を続けている。
学歴だけがあの人の心のよりどころだ。

支え can be used in a similar manner, but 心の拠り所 sounds more negative to me. However, when translating "I use self-deprecating humor as a crutch to hide my insecurities", 心の拠り所 might not be a good option because it usually refers to some specific thing one really relies on for a long time. In this case, (不安を隠すための)逃げ道(として), 逃避(として) or 盾(として) can be used instead.
